How to handle the completion of the startSystemMove method in Qt
How to handle the completion of the startSystemMove or startSystemResize method?
I need something like the mouseReleaseEvent method, but it doesn't work since I'm delegating window control to the system. (This is exactly what the startSystemMove or startSystemResize methods are responsible for)
My example:
class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget* parent = nullptr)
    {
        setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    }
    ~Widget() override = default;

protected:
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event) override
    {
        windowHandle()->startSystemMove();
        QWidget::mouseMoveEvent(event);
    }

    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* event) override
    {
        qDebug() << "mouse is release";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    auto mainWindow = new Widget();
    mainWindow->show();

    return QApplication::exec();
}


In trying to handle the completion of window movement, I'm trying to solve a number of other problems, such as
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    auto mainWindow = new Widget();

    auto button = new QPushButton(mainWindow);
    button->setStyleSheet("QPushButton:hover{background-color: red}");

    mainWindow->show();

    return QApplication::exec();
}

After moving the window, when you hover over the button, it does not turn red. If you have no idea how to solve this, then there may be no point in trying to handle the completion of the window move.

Your question is unclear. Can you clarify what you actually want to do (or need to know)?

@musicamante I'm dragging a rectangle (an object of the Widget class), I need to handle the moment at which I release the left mouse button, what exactly is not clear?

What you actually explained in your update is exactly what wasn't clear previously. This may be related to some changes that were introduced in Qt5.15 (and later 6.* versions, I don't really know which). See QTBUG-69716 and the more recent QTBUG-91077, which was fixed only since 6.3 (and therefore probably unfixable in Qt5). Having more details about your environment may help (starting from OS/Qt version, and wm/display configuration if under Linux).

@musicamante Thank you very much for the answer. Indeed, the latest editions of Qt6 do not have this bug.
